# Having a key error when using group and sum in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I would like to use groupby and sum a csv file

```
 a      b   c   d
1111    0.1 1   1
1111    0   1   0
2222    0.2 1   1
1111    0.2 2   1
2222        1   1
1111    0.3 2   0
3333    0.4 1   1
3333    0.5 2   1
1111    0.6 2   1
```

e: # if b < 0.2, group column a and sum of column c

f:   # If b >= 0.2 group column a and sum of column c

g: # If d = 1, and b >= 0.2, g is sum of c

h: # If d = 0 and b < 0.2, h is sum of c

expected output:

```
       e    f   g    h
1111   2    6   4    1
2222        1   1
3333        3   3
```

I try:

```
df1 = df[(df['d'] == 1) & (df['b'] >= 0.2)] 
df1.groupby('a')['c'].sum()
```

However, I got key error in a large file:

> pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc, pandas.hastable.PobjectHashTable.get_item in column a.

Comment: I try to tidy up the post but don't know how to put the layout. Thanks for editing. For the code, I try to use groupb and sum but I had a key error at column a. Something is about pandas hashtable...

Comment: You should consider putting the error into the question.

Comment: I worked out the columns g successfully in a small sample by using df1 = df[(df['d'] == 1) & (df['b'] >= 0.2)], df1.groupby('a')['c'].sum(). However, I got key error in a large file: pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc, pandas.hastable.PobjectHashTable.get_item in column a... dunno why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try different approach:

First create conditions columns - `e` to `h` and then use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) for filling this mask with values of column `c`. Last use [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df['e'] = df['b'] < 0.2
df['f'] = df['b'] >= 0.2
df['g'] = (df['d'] == 1) & (df['b'] >= 0.2)
df['h'] = (df['d'] == 0) & (df['b'] < 0.2)
print df
      a    b  c  d      e      f      g      h
0  1111  0.1  1  1   True  False  False  False
1  1111  0.0  1  0   True  False  False   True
2  2222  0.2  1  1  False   True   True  False
3  1111  0.2  2  1  False   True   True  False
4  2222  NaN  1  1  False  False  False  False
5  1111  0.3  2  0  False   True  False  False
6  3333  0.4  1  1  False   True   True  False
7  3333  0.5  2  1  False   True   True  False
8  1111  0.6  2  1  False   True   True  False

df.loc[:, ['e','f','g','h']]= df.loc[:, ['e','f','g','h']].mul(df.c, axis=0)
print df
      a    b  c  d  e  f  g  h
0  1111  0.1  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  1111  0.0  1  0  1  0  0  1
2  2222  0.2  1  1  0  1  1  0
3  1111  0.2  2  1  0  2  2  0
4  2222  NaN  1  1  0  0  0  0
5  1111  0.3  2  0  0  2  0  0
6  3333  0.4  1  1  0  1  1  0
7  3333  0.5  2  1  0  2  2  0
8  1111  0.6  2  1  0  2  2  0
```

```
df1 = df.groupby('a').sum()
print df1[['e','f','g','h']]
      e  f  g  h
a               
1111  2  6  4  1
2222  0  1  1  0
3333  0  3  3  0
```

Comment: Why is "a" no *key* anymore? Why is it written in the second row?